# Taiga frontend dist

Tags: python, apache, vps, taiga

**Mi situation:**
I have been instaling taiga for 2 days.
Finally I got the backend installed. When I make

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/
```

It answer properly but when I do the same with my public ip it answer with a connection error.

In other way I want to access to the frontend. The official guide says that you have to **Expose the dist directory under a static file web server**

I?m installing it on my **Centos 6.5 Vps** with apache as a http server.

I have tried creating **/etc/httpd/conf.d/taiga.conf** as

```
<VirtualHost *:9000>
    ServerName emilio
    ServerAdmin mail@mail.com
    DocumentRoot /home/taiga/taiga-front-dist/dist/
    ErrorLog logs/redmine_error_log
    <Directory "/home/taiga/taiga-front-dist/dist/">
            Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
```

But when I access to miip:9000 it doesn't show the index.html or anything.

so, my question is **how I make to serve the frontend in this port?**
Any help will be apreciated.

Greetings